# Resolving AuthenticationStateProvider in startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, telerik-reporting

I have a Blazor project. In startup.cs AuthenticationStateProvider is injected at the backend. I am using it is a constructor for one class.

```
 public class ServiceClass : IServiceClass
{
    public ServiceClass(AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider)
    {
        _authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
    }
    private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider;
    public async Task<string> GetIdentity()
    {
        var identity="";
        return identity;
    } 
}
```

And ServiceClass is also injected in startup.cs

```
services.AddScoped<IServiceClass, ServiceClass>();
```

Now there is another service that I need to inject which is dependent on ServiceClass

```
 services.AddScoped<IReportServiceConfiguration>(sp =>
            new ReportServiceConfiguration
            {
                ReportingEngineConfiguration = sp.GetService<IConfiguration>(),
                HostAppId = "Html5DemoAppCore",
                Storage = new FileStorage(),
                ReportSourceResolver = new CustomReportSourceResolver(),
            }
            ); ;
```

But I cannot use **ReportSourceResolver = new CustomReportSourceResolver()**, because it has serviceClass in constructor. And I cannot use sp.getService() because then authenticationStateProvider gets returned null(due to a different scope i think). How can I register this last service?

I have already tried to use IScopeFactory to replace class constructors, but figured we cannot use that because creating a new scope returns AuthenticationStateProvider null.
I have tried to use

```
 var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var service = serviceProvider.GetService<CustomReportResolver>();
```

That doesn't work, I assume because it needs all the required services to be registered before BuildServiceProvider() and we do not know at what point AuthenticationStateProvider gets injected.

Tried using Autofac instead of .Net Core dependency injection but faced the same problem because AuthenticationStateProvider is still registered by .net core DI system.

Comment: Don't instantiate `ReportServiceConfiguration` manually. Use a constructor that can get the necessary parameters from dependency injection. It looks like 3 of the values are already OK, you just need to either get rid of the hard-coded `HostAppId` or use another class which you can inject

Comment: ReportServiceConfiguration is part of the Telerik Reporting package. I cannot edit that class, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Inject the default `ReportServiceConfiguration` and manually set `HostAppId`? It has a public setter anyway. Otherwise you'll need to use `sp.GetRequiredService<service>` for Storage/ReportSourceResolver

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Can you please tell me why I was downvoted ? And removed the tags from Blazor to C# while anybody who is going to face this problem will be specific to Telerik Reporting for Blazor?

Comment: I cannot comment on the downvotes. Blazor is completely irrelevant, this is just a dependency injection question, and the exact same question could be asked in any .NET Standard project using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Comment: If I use sp.getRequiredService<CustomReportResolver>(), because CustomReportResolver is dependent on ServiceClass and ServiceClass is using AuthenticationStateProvider. AuthenticationStateProvider gets returned null. (Because of a new scope I think)